# Program that inputs the number of days in January, (C++ beginner) (from 1 to 31) (separ. at tens), and outputs #'s written out

Tags: beginner, c++17, visual-studio

```
// January

// This program inputs the # of days in January 1-31

// Brandon Summerlin

// 2/03/2023

    #include <iostream>
    using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

    int main() {
    //inputs the numbers
    cout << "input the number from 01 to 31: ";
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    const int singles = number % 10;
    const int tens = number / 10;

    cout << "tens: " << tens << endl;
    cout << "singles:" << singles << endl;

    //singles
    }
```

Comment: (realized I forgot to close the ending bracket so I apologize for that one)

Comment: Welcome to the site. I went ahead and added the closing brace when I reformatted.

Comment: Your title and the comment mentions January, but the program itself has nothing about January or 31. This is a bit confusing. Did you intend your program to always output the number of days in January (31), or check that the user enters 31, or something else?

Answer (score 6):

Not a bad start.  Since the program logic does what it does very cleanly, the only real tips I have are about formatting.

It’s customary, and a good idea, to indent the body of each of your blocks.  In this program, there’s only one.  So:

```
int main() {
    //inputs the numbers
    cout << "input the number from 01 to 31: ";
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    const int singles = number % 10;
    const int tens = number / 10;

    cout << "tens: " << tens << endl;
    cout << "singles:" << singles << endl;

    //singles
}
```

You should put in comments that are helpful, but avoid saying things that are obvious from the code itself.  One thing that can go wrong is when the comment `//singles` seems to have gotten stranded at the end.  You gave your variables good names, so a comment like `//inputs the numbers` in front of `cin >> number` seems either misleading (You input only one number, but the comment says “numbers.”) or unnecessary.

You write on a single line,

```
using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;
```

You normally want to put statements like these on their own lines.  In C++17 and up, you can instead write,

```
using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;
```

I’d recommend putting your header files and `using` declarations in alphabetical, or some other logical, order, so you can easily see whether something is or isn’t there.

I also put a `using` declaration like this in my programs, because `std::` was only added to `cout` and `cin` in ’98, and I’m old-fashioned.  It would be a very bad idea to have, for example, `using std::string;`, because there is a *lot* of C++ code out there that uses the name `string` for something different. But `cout`, `cin` and `endl` are safe, because they’ve been around since the beginning and no C++ program ever declares some other `cout`.  Not everyone agrees (and you can read the comments if you want to hear that perennial debate).  “Never import a name from the standard library into the global namespace,” is an easier rule to follow than, “Only add an identifier to the global namespace if you’re sure that no other module will ever re-use the same name,” so that’s what some people recommend.

Finally, if I don’t bring this up, someone else is sure to: most people here recommend you end lines with `<< '\n'` rather than `<< endl`, unless you genuinely do need to flush your output.  This will give you slightly better performance.

Comment: I agree with everything you said, but only have 1 thing to add: don't use `using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;` at all. This tends to pollute the global namespace and can lead to clashes in names. For a tiny program, like this, it's fine but it's better to start with good practices from early on. This isn't enough to write a review about, so, I am giving this point to you.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I personally have a `using` lone like that, too. I also `#include <stdlib.h>` instead of `<cstdlib>`.  It’s because I was writing C and C++ before `namespace std` was invented, and I never switched to `std::cout` or `std::memcpy`. No C++ program ever written has some other `cout` or `memcpy` in it, unlike, say, `array` or `string`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel If you want to use `std::` all the time, instead of arbitrarily dropping it only for some bits and pieces that were around before C++98. or that I mostly used in C, well, that’s more consistent and probably going to make more sense to anyone younger than me.

Comment: The "problem" doesn't manifest in this example. But if you try to create something more complex, throwing all the stuff into the global namespace is a pretty bad idea. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but to just keep in mind to avoid this on more complex programs. Best practices should be practiced from the beginning, and trying to prevent an old habit is harder than creating good habits.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It would be bad to throw everything into the global namespace. But `cout` and `cin` are fine.

Comment: I agree with you. But you completely missed the point I've made.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Respectfully, I don’t think I did. If you bring `string` into the global namespace, that could be a serious problem because a huge number of programs define their own `string`.  The canonical answer to why you shouldn’t import `namespace std` says something like, “When I see `std::string`, I know it’s from the STL. When I see `string`, I’m not sure.” This never happens with `cout` or `cin`. The other thing that could go wrong is if someone adds an identifier to a namespace you import that then breaks your code. This doesn’t happen when you enumerate your imports.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel If the point you’re making is that “Never do it,” is a simpler rule to remember than, “These few exceptions are okay,” sure. But these exceptions are okey.

Comment: Yeah, but you should point this out in the answer. This is the *exception* to the "rule".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Okay, I did.